# Question about the units of an operator related to the time evolution operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, dimensional-analysis, units, time-evolution

Let $U(t, t_0)$ be the unitary time evolution operator. Define an operator $\Lambda (t):= \partial_t [U(t, t_0)] U^\dagger (t, t_0)$.  This operator turns out to be independent of $t_0$. Now, the [notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_06.pdf)  I'm reading use this operator to derive the Schrodinger equation from unitary time evolution, and they state that this operator has units $[\Lambda(t)] = s^{-1}$. Why is this? (This is a crucial step in the derivation, because the operator $H(t) := i \hbar \Lambda(t) $ has units of energy, and we define this to be the Hamiltonian.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U$ and $U^\dagger$ are mutual inverses so their product is dimensionless. The only dimension   comes from the $d/dt$, which has units of s$^{-1}$.